# Is it acceptable to use `to` to create a `Pair`?

Tags: kotlin

[`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) is an infix function within the standard library. It can be used to create `Pair`s concisely:

```
0 to "hero"
```

in comparison with:

```
Pair(0, "hero")
```

Typically, it is used to initialize `Map`s concisely:

```
mapOf(0 to "hero", 1 to "one", 2 to "two")
```

However, there are other situations in which one needs to create a `Pair`. For instance:

```
"to be or not" to "be"

(0..10).map { it to it * it }
```

Is it acceptable, *stylistically*, to (ab)use `to` in this manner?

Comment: Have no fear — it seems a perfectly sensible question to me :-)  (Though I must admin that me = someone who hasn't asked _any_ questions yet…)

Comment: I would use `to` if it's clear from the context what is going on and `Pair` if it's helpful for readers, that a `Pair` is used in this context... a simple example: `fun whenOmittingReturnValue() = Pair(1, "many")` might be better than `fun omittingReturnValue() = 1 to "many"` ... of course, in this specific context `fun dontOmitReturnValue() : Pair<Int, String> = 1 to "many"` might be the even better choice... for me, it mainly depends on the context... `.associate { it.some to it.other }` would be totally ok for me... as in that case I don't mind that I have a `Pair` underneath...

Comment: or in other words: (for me) `to` hides the `Pair`-creation when you go over the code quickly (so that you are dealing with a `Pair` here is secondary)... writing `Pair` explicitly shows it more clearly and makes sense in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Just because some language features are provided does not mean they are better over certain things. A `Pair` can be used instead of `to` and vice versa. What becomes a real issue is that, does your code still remain simple, would it require some reader to read the previous story to understand the current one? In your last `map` example, it does not give a hint of what it's doing. Imagine someone reading `{ it to it * it}`, they would be most likely confused. I would say this is an abuse.

`to` infix offer a nice syntactical sugar, IMHO it should be used in conjunction with a nicely named variable that tells the reader what this **something** `to` **something** is.  For example:

```
val heroPair = Ironman to Spiderman //including a 'pair' in the variable name tells the story what 'to' is doing.
```

Or you could use scoping functions

```
(Ironman to Spiderman).let { heroPair -> }
```

Comment: Is it the precedence that you find unclear, or the presence of `to` at all?  Would `it to (it * it)` seem clearer?

Comment: No, I don't find precedence unclear. What you wrote definitely makes it 'clear'. But I would want to prefer some other name than `it`. Maybe, a `key` or whatever that is relevant to one's block of code. `it` is not bad at all, an `it` for example would be pleasing to read where you need to execute a specific block of code, like, `fun total(first: Int, second: Int) = getTotal(first, second).also { print(it)`. The code example is bad, what I am trying to say is that `it` sounds more suitable where the code line sounds more like an English statement.

Comment: Ah, so it's the repeated use of `it` that seems unclear.  While I'm not disagreeing with that, I don't think it's quite answering the question, which was about `to` and which situations are suitable for using `to` instead of constructing a `Pair` explicitly.  Would you use `to` in a `map{…}` expression?

Comment: Honestly, as long as it does not make the reader scratch their head for a bit, `to` is a shorter than an explicit declaration. I would myself use it by giving the variable a clear meaning of the map just like I made an example in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**I don't think there's an authoritative answer to this.**  The only examples in the Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#read-only-map) are for creating simple constant maps with `mapOf()`, but there's no hint that `to` shouldn't be used elsewhere.

So it'll come down to a matter of personal taste…

For me, **I'd be happy to use it anywhere it represents a mapping** of some kind, so in a `map{…}` expression would seem clear to me, just as much as in a `mapOf(…)` list.  Though (as mentioned elsewhere) it's not often used in complex expressions, so I might use parentheses to keep the precedence clear, and/or simplify the expression so they're not needed.

Where it *doesn't* indicate a mapping, I'd be much more hesitant to use it.  For example, if you have a method that returns two values, it'd probably be clearer to use an explicit `Pair`.  (Though in that case, it'd be clearer still to define a simple data class for the return value.)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for personal perspective so here is mine.
I found this syntax is a huge win for simple code, especial in reading code. Reading code with parenthesis, a lot of them, caused mental stress, imagine you have to review/read thousand lines of code a day ;(